# How do I change the color or text in an anchor tag by targeting the class within the anchor tag?

Tags: css

can some one explain why the following happens:

```
<a href="#" class="test">Test</a>

<style type="text/css">
.test {
border: thin solid blue;
color: red;
}
</style>
```

This only creates the border but doesn't turn the text red when using a class.

However, this works in turning the text red when using an id instead:

```
<a href="#" id="test">Test</a>

<style type="text/css">
#test {
border: thin solid blue;
color: red;
}
</style>
```

Why does the class not change the text color, while using id does work?

Thanks!

Comment: If you run each of these isolated samples in something like jsFiddle, they will display the same thing. The problem isn't here. Likely something is overwriting the style you've defined with the class.

Comment: It's the same either way. See: http://jsfiddle.net/mD5us/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mD5us/3/)

```
 <a href="#" class="test">Test</a>

 <style type="text/css">
a.test {
border: thin solid blue;
color: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mD5us/4/

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="test">Test</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
​body div a.test{
    color:yellow;
}
body div .test{
    color:brown;
}
body a.test{
    color:purple;
}
body .test{
    color: orange;
}
a.test{
    color:green;
}
.test {
    border: thin solid blue;
    color: red;
}
```

You might think that the link will be red, but it will actually be yellow since that is the most specific declaration.

Comment: Really, that helped a lot too... I had thought the last one would override any type of declaration that ended up effecting the text.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the style tag into this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   a.test{
      border: thin solid blue;
      color: red;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Totaly true. It went to fast