# I'm editing the CSS of the navigation bar in WordPress, need help changing the color

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm editing the CSS of the main navigation bar in WordPress, need help in changing the color of the last element in the navigation bar.

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="full-menu nav"><li id="menu-item-602" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-602"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/actu/">Actu</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-607" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-607"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/mode/">Mode</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-604" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-604"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/bien-etre/">Bien-être</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-603"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/beaute/">Beauté</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-605" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-605"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/cuisine/">Cuisine</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-609" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-609"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/vie-pratique/">VIE Pratique</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-606" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-606"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/culture/">Culture</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-608" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-608"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/evasion/">Évasion</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-725" class="srvce menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-725"><a href="http://demowebsite.com/category/services/">Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to change the color of the last anchor tag text 'Service' which you'll see in the last < li > element. It should be red. The problem I'm facing is that I cannot get to refer to the specific anchor tag text inside the li element.

I've tried giving it a class while creating the menu but it didn't help. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831999/how-to-change-color-of-only-text-of-anchor-link try this

Comment: Exact answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870009/how-do-i-change-the-color-or-text-in-an-anchor-tag-by-targeting-the-class-within

Add a class to it and use it in the css of your page.
Tag : 
`<a href="....." class="test">Services</a>`
Css :
 `<style type="text/css">
a.test {
border: thin solid blue;
color: red;
}
</style>`

Comment: Thanks Pat, but the trouble was that I was unable to add a class in the anchor tag as I don't know how to add classes and ids to elements in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want last element of the menu to be specific color try this:

```
#menu-main-menu li:last-child a {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I was not sure on how to select the last element.